# Install4j Licences uninstallation

Tags: install4j

i installed install4j licence version on my machine which is for one machine only now i want to remove that from my machine and want to install on some another machine for that which problems will come. And please tell me solutions for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just uninstall install4j and select the "Remove licensing information" check box in the uninstaller.